# How to load Fonts in Jetpack Compose Desktop?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose-text, compose-desktop

In Jetpack Compose for android you can do this:

```kotlin
val fontFamily = FontFamily(
    Font(
        resId = R.font.my_font_400_regular,
        weight = FontWeight.W400,
        style = FontStyle.Normal
    ),
    Font(
        resId = R.font.my_font_400_italic,
        weight = FontWeight.W400,
        style = FontStyle.Italic
    )
)
```

But for Desktop the Filestructure is different and I have no Access to `R.font.my_font_400_regular` since 'R' is a Android Resource feature.

Answer (score 19):

Put your `.ttf` font file in the `src > main > resources` folder. And then use:

```
val fontFamily = FontFamily(
    Font(
        resource = "font.ttf",
        weight = FontWeight.W400,
        style = FontStyle.Normal
    )
)
```

Comment: The Font here is androidx.compose.ui.text.platform.Font

Comment: Interesting fact: for some reason font files other than `.ttf` will not work. I spend some time trying to make it work with `.otf` font files, but to no avail.  So just keep this in mind. `.ttf` only

Answer (score 5):

Also, if you are using multiple fonts and want them to each be in their own sub-directory in resources like

resources/fonts/example1/

then make sure to include that directory in your 'resource' string in the Font creation.

```
Font(
    resource = "fonts/example1/examplefont_bold.ttf",
    weight = FontWeight.Bold,
    style = FontStyle.Normal
)
```

Probably obvious, but just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Other sample

```
val LatoFontFamily = FontFamily(
    Font(resource = "Fonts/Lato-Light.ttf", weight = FontWeight.Light),
    Font(resource = "Fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf", weight = FontWeight.Normal),
    Font(resource = "Fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf", weight = FontWeight.Bold)
)

val LatoFontBoldFamily = FontFamily(
    Font(resource = "Fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf", weight = FontWeight.Bold)
)

val typography = Typography(
    defaultFontFamily = LatoFontFamily,
    h1 = TextStyle(
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
        fontSize = 96.sp,
        letterSpacing = (-1.5).sp
    ),
    h2 = TextStyle(
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
        fontSize = 60.sp,
        letterSpacing = (-0.5).sp
    )
)
```