# How do I use fonts in Jetpack Compose for Desktop?

Tags: kotlin, fonts, jvm, desktop, jetbrains-compose

I'm trying to use some font ttf files placed in `src/main/resources/fonts/` in JetBrains Compose for Desktop. How do I use the font files in the function `androidx.compose.ui.text.font.Font()`? I tried using the `R.fonts.font_file` mentioned in many online articles, but it seems like it only works on Android.

I know that there's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66546700/how-to-load-fonts-in-jetpack-compose-desktop). He's facing the exact same problem I'm having here. I've tried this. Unfortunately, it didn't work. The only answer in the question I linked above says that the solution was to put the font files in `src/main/resources` and use:

```
Font(
    resource = "font.ttf",
    weight = FontWeight.W400,
    style = FontStyle.Normal,
)
```

But it doesn't work. The `androidx.compose.ui.text.font.Font()` function on my machine requires 3 params, `resId`, `weight`, and `style`.

```
public fun Font(
    resId: Int,
    weight: FontWeight,
    style: FontStyle,
)
```

(copied from the Idea tooltip)

As you can see, it requires a `resId`: **Int**. How am I supposed to specify it in an Int?

Since JetBrains Compose for Desktop is still in its early beta stage, resources I could find on the web is really scarce. I tried searching for "kotlin resource id" to find the way to refer to the font file as an ID, but all I could find are really Android-targeted things. I also tried searching for "jetpack compose desktop font" and "jetbrains compose font", and the results I get are also flooded with Android things. Yes, I tried using "-android" in the search query, but all that's left in the results are irrelevant. The question I linked is the only thing I could find about Jetpack Compose for Desktop font.

Here's most of my [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQohM.png).

Here is the [tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBT8h.png) that IntelliJ Idea shows when I hover over `Font()`. It isn't that useful, is it?

Kotlin version: 1.5.10
Jetpack compose version: 0.5.0-build225 (latest pre-release)
By the way, I'm using Manjaro Linux on a MacBook if it matters.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `androidx.compose.ui.text.font.Font` for this. Import `androidx.compose.ui.text.platform.Font` instead.

Perhaps counter-intuitively, `androidx.compose.ui.text.platform.Font` is a valid parameter type in a `androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily`, and supports `resource`, `weight` and `style`.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I use "jost_regular.ttf".

1. Put `jost_regular.ttf` in `jvmMain/resources/font/` folder.
2. In `Theme.kt`:

```
package jetbrains.compose.calculator.resources

import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.platform.Font

...

val jostFontFamily = FontFamily(
    fonts = listOf(
        Font(
            resource = "font/jost_regular.ttf",
            weight = FontWeight.W400,
            style = FontStyle.Normal
        )
    )
)
```

3. Usage:

```
    Text(
        text = mainOutput.value .text,
        style = TextStyle(
            fontSize = 48.sp,
            fontFamily = jetbrains.compose.calculator.resources.jostFontFamily
        ),
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        softWrap = false,
        maxLines = 1,
    )
```